# Prove continuity of piecewise function using epsilon-delta

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Suppose we have a function $\phi$ so that

$$\phi (x)=\cases{f(x) & \text{ if } x\le 0\\
      g(x)& \text{ if } x>0.}$$
where  $f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,0]$ and $g$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, and suppose $f(0)=g(0)$ (that is, the value of $g(0)$ if $g$ were extended to a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$, which it can be by some theorem). For example, we could have:

$$\phi (x)=\cases{x & \text{ if } x\le 0\\
      x^2& \text{ if } x>0.}$$

How can we rigorously show that $\phi$ is continuous at $0$, using either the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition OR the equivalent definition that $\phi$ is continuous at $x_0$ iff for every $(x_n)$ with $x_n \to x_0$ we have $\phi(x_n)\to \phi(x_0)$?

I have seen this proof by looking at the both the left and right side continuity (such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369078/show-continuity-using-epsilon-delta-definition-for-piecewise-function)), but I'm not sure how that's rigorous only assuming the above two ways to prove continuity (since we have to consider every $(x_n)$, not just $(x_n)$ approaching from the left or the right). I suppose a proof of this left-right continuity would also suffice, but a proof using either of the two above methods in a nice way would be slicker I think, if possible.

Is the way to go about it by actually extending $g$ to the extra point at $0$ and noting that $g(0)=f(0)$? If so, how can that be made rigorously precise?

Comment: the only problem where $\phi(x)$ can be discontinuous is at $0$, and there, the right and left limits exist, and both are equal to $\phi(0)$. with the  $\epsilon, \delta$ it will be exactly the same, since when $x_0 > 0$ we look only to $g(x)$, and when $x_0 < 0$ only to $f(x)$, while at $x_0=0$ you'll write the limits I mentioned explicitly in term of  $\epsilon, \delta$

Comment: and the definition of the continuity at $x_0$ needs 3 steps : $\lim_{x \to x_0^+} \phi(x)$ exists, $\lim_{x \to x_0^-} \phi(x)$ exists, and both are equal to $\phi(x_0)$.  (consider the function $\sin(1/x)$ to see an example of function where the right and left limits don't even exist)

Answer (score 1):

By continuity of $f$ and $g$,

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta_{f,\epsilon} >0, |x| \leq \delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)| \leq \epsilon$

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta_{g,\epsilon} >0, |x| \leq \delta \implies |g(x)-g(0)| \leq \epsilon$

Hence Let $\delta_{\epsilon}=\min(\delta_{f,\epsilon},\delta_{g,\epsilon})$,

$\forall \epsilon>0, |x|\leq \delta_{\epsilon} \implies |\phi(x)-\phi(0)|\leq \epsilon$